# QAbstractItemModel change backing data outside begin/end functions

Tags: c++, qt

**TL;DR**: How can I modify backing data structures for subclass o `QAbstractItemModel` beyond `beginInsertRows`/`endInsertRows` functions, taken I can move actual modification of backing arrey before it or after? This needed because backing data structure is often modified through its own interface, and `QAbstractItemModel` serves as merely its view to integrate into Qt GUI.

I have certain tree-like data model in my application. And I have Qt data model inherited from QAbstractItem model to link it with Qt tree control.
Base data model gets changed independently, because using it everywhere in app would be too cumbersome.

The issue itself:
Base data model emits signal when children set of one of its elements changes. I connect Qt data model with this signal. And only delete index which represents that item. The item itself still exists in initial array, and gets removed only after emit ends. This causes Qt to try reference that same index in the next iteration of event loop when it contains pointer to already deleted entity.

The question is:
Is there a way to properly update indices in Qt data model, when actual data storage can be affected by some external signal or code? Documentation says that adding/removing/moving elements is only allowed between corresponding begin/end calls. But that would be very cumbersome, if even possible in my case.

Comment: Why would it be cumbersome? You only have to implement that in the add/remove function of your data. And then you use those to make changes.Don't do direct array manipulations. The only other way would be to keep reloading the entire model, forcing the reloading of all delegate data. That is not efficient.

Comment: @dtech Backing data is managed by 3rd party library, so it may add/remove elements on its own. I simply cannot force all modification paths go through QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: So how is the view supposed to know if any changes occur? By magic?

Comment: That 3rd party library can notify about such changes. But these events come when change already happened.

Comment: You could try just calling the functions after, but issues are probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to refactor logic in such a way that internal model sends pairs of events, one before actual operation and one after. Changing logic of internal wrapper objects allowed to remove them right between those "event brackets", effectively solving issue. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the index contains a pointer to the underlying item which is already deleted by the moment you can use `QAbstractItemModel` facilities to notify the view about the deletion. So I suppose you use [QModelIndex::internalPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#internalPointer) to map the row/column/parent concepts of `QAbstractItemModel` to the items of your original underlying model.

Instead of that you could use [QModelIndex::internalId](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#internalId) to map the items from your underlying model to the indexes of `QAbstractItemModel`. Unlike the dangling pointer, the unique identifier can be used to safely check whether the item exists in the underlying model at any time. If it doesn't exist, it is always possible to return empty `QVariant` from `QAbstractItemModel::data` method. It may still "surprise" the view as some items' values would change from actual values to empty ones behind the view's back - but it is still much better than having to deal with the potentially dangling pointer.